# Soap request works fine in Soapui but not in python - ZEEP - SUDS

Tags: python, soap, soapui, suds, zeep

I have a request to a soap webservice which is working fine in SoapUi. I'd like to call this webservice in a python script.

I tried some modules : zeep, suds,... but I always have an SSL error.

Here are the infos :

https://37.71XXXXXXACONYX?wsdl

Basic authentification : username + password

Authentification type : preemptive

I have the xml available in SoapUi.

Does someone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot !!

I tried :

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)
client = Client('https://37.71XXXXXXACONYX?wsdl',
            transport=Transport(session=session))
```